# jquery - 2 clicks issue

Tags: jquery, events, click

I have a problem with click event.

```
    function update (id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: {id:id},
                success: function(data){
                $(".expand").html(data);
                response(".test");
                },
            });
        }

    function response(object){
         $(this).one("click", function(){
              alert("Finished");
         }).click(function(){
              alert("Hello");
         });
    }
```

function update is called with a div click (onclick event).

If only one click is fired, function response doesn't work. So I need another click on it. How could I run both 2 functions with just a click?

Answer (score 0):

If you've copy/pasted from your own code, note that 'function' is misspelled in `fucntion response`.

Comment: Actually, I mentioned about function update and function response. I want to call these 2 functions with just a click.

Comment: Yeah, I realized I misread your question and have removed that part of my answer. Note the edit I've made, though, that could point out another problem.

Comment: Sorry about that. It just a typing error. And this doesn't exists in my code.